# Cython installed but can't be imported

Tags: python, cython

I installed Cython using `apt-get install cython3`. But when I run a script with Python 3 that tries to `from Cython.Build import cythonize`, I get the message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'`

What am I missing to run this script?

Comment: I'd check you haven't installed Cython for Python 2, but are using Python 3 (or vice versa).

Comment: Indeed, the `from Cython.Build import cythonize` command works for Python2 but not for Python3. Yet the `cython3` package is also installed.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try to install Cython using pip by `pip install cython`.

Comment: I was really trying to avoid having to use pip, but I guess I might not have a choice.

Comment: I'm thinking perhaps apt-get didn't install cython to the correct location, but with pip you know python will have to see it.